# Isn't it too complex to make REST call based on Google I/O Android REST client applications suggested

Tags: android, rest, service, android-asynctask

Based on Google I/O video, http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html, I got this question...

No matter the call is rest calls or normal http calls, they will have same issue mentioned in this video. So that means it is not good implementation if we use asynctask from activity.

Isn't it too complex to always implement Service and content provider even we just need to make a simple http call to a server and get a bunch of text to display on android?

This really confuse me, what do you guys think?

Answer (score 1):

yeah its a lot of work for a one-off service call. Lately I have been using the new [loader api](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html) for this type of thing.  More specifically the AsyncLoader